# SQL Error in Casting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to join date and time fields in order to select the latest status at a certain point in time using the following code...

```
select  max(CONVERT(DATETIME, S.Start_date, 108) 
    + ISNULL(STUFF(case when len(S.start_time) < 4 then '0' + S.start_time else S.start_time end,3,0,':'),'23:59') as LATST
        , computer_number
        , event_key
        , exam_key
    from    CRIS_status S
        where cast(Start_date as datetime) <= '17 Jul 2016 23:59:59'
    group by computer_number, event_key, exam_key
```

and i get the following error messgae Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1...

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Any reason why Start_date and start_time are not only one datetime field?

Comment: I did the same type of casting here on my environment and the result was perfect, no error here (Command(s) completed successfully).

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `Datetime` with a `Varchar` which probably gives error

Try with this...

```
select  max(CONVERT(DATETIME, S.Start_date, 108) 
    + ISNULL(STUFF(case when len(S.start_time) < 4 then '0' + S.start_time else S.start_time end,3,0,':'),'23:59') as LATST
        , computer_number
        , event_key
        , exam_key
    from    CRIS_status S
        where cast(Start_date as datetime) <= cast('17 Jul 2016 23:59:59' as datetime)
    group by computer_number, event_key, exam_key
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use unambiguous date format

```
select  max(CONVERT(DATETIME, S.Start_date, 108) 
    + ISNULL(STUFF(case when len(S.start_time) < 4 then '0' + S.start_time else S.start_time end,3,0,':')
 ,'23:59') as LATST
        , computer_number
        , event_key
        , exam_key
    from    CRIS_status S
        where cast(Start_date as datetime) < '20160718'
    group by computer_number, event_key, exam_key
```

Comment: ooh, thank you Madhivanan, I'll try it and let you know.